# How to pass existing enum as WCF Service parameter?

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to pass enum type value to my WCF Service. However this enum type(for example `SqlDbType`) is not created by me and I can't modify it. After searching on google, I learn that enum type passed as WCF Service parameter must be added `DataContractAttribute` and its member must be added `EnumMemberAttribute`, I wonder if it's possible to do this work at runtime, for example, when service starts. Here is my code which is not working:

```
public class AppInitializer
{
    public static void AppInitialize()
    {
        Type enumType = typeof(SqlDbType);
        Attribute[] dataContractAttribute = { new DataContractAttribute()};
        TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(enumType, dataContractAttribute);
        Attribute[] enumMemberAttribute = { new EnumMemberAttribute() };
        foreach (object value in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
        {
            TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(value, enumMemberAttribute);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just pass the int and cast, all sorted? i personally thought enums just serialize. however maybe you could try `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(MyEnum))]`

Comment: @MichaelRandall, I store the enum value in dictionary<string, object> as value,  if pass the int, how can I know it is of enum type or int type?

Comment: Id be surprised if `dictionary<string, object>` worked at all.

Comment: @V.S. Sorry for reply so late. It has been several months since I checked this post the last time, I remember I solved my problem in another way: using `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(MyEnum))]` on ServiceContract and `[KnownType(typeof(MyEnum))]` on DataContract, so I've not tried your answer yet. I think your answer is great and am sure it will work, but it need more codes in my case.

Answer (score 0):

How about recreating your own enum out of the other one and add relevant attributes to the former as needed. I know this is not a runtime solution, but it is easy enough and could be done within a couple of minutes.

Considering the following 3rd party enum:

```
enum ThirPartyEnum
{
    Zero = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
```

Create your own one that way:

```
[DataContract(Name = "MyEnum")]
enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("Zero")]
    [EnumMember]
    Zero= ThirPartyEnum.Zero,

    [Description("One")]
    [EnumMember]
    One = ThirPartyEnum.One,

    [Description("Two")]
    [EnumMember]
    Two = ThirPartyEnum.Two
}
```